# Вопрос по сложению столбцов из таблицы mysql

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте! Имеется таблица с двумя значениями

`ID_IL,IL_LVL,IL_CLASS,IL_NAME,IL_COST,IL_KEY,IL_MIN_DMG,IL_MAX_DMG,IL_DEF,IL_STR,IL_DEX,
IL_INT,IL_SPD,IL_IL_MAX_PROCH,IL_TREBUET,IL_IMAGE,IL_SRC,IL_NO,ID_USERS,IL_SHANS_BLOCK,
IL_VES,IL_COUNT`

Нужно сложить две ячейки допустим ячейку с ID_IL 1 и ID_IL 2. Не понимаю, как это можно сделать...

Comment: Сложить как? Как числа или как строки? Google, Yandex и F1 тебе в помощь.

Comment: значения числовые

Answer (score 1):

```
$N;//номер нужной строки
$M;//номер следующей строки. Не обязательню плюс один.
$sql = "select `ID_IL`,`IL_LVL`,...,`IL_VES`,`IL_COUNT` from `table` where `id`=$N or `id`=$M";
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if(mysql_num_rows($res)==2){
  $row1 = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC);
  $row2 = mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC);
}
foreach($row1 as $key=>$value){
  $row1[$key] = $row2[$key]+$value;
}
unset($row2);
print_r($row1);//при желании, можно запихать опять в базу
```

Comment: во,это уже поинтереснее

Comment: а то головой об стену бьюсь уже не знаю как подсчитать общий вес всех вещей в инвентаре,спасибо

Comment: один вопрос можно ли это переделать все не в массив а в обычные цифры,так все работает автору респект .выводит Array ( [IL_VES] => 2.2 ) можно ли сделать просто 2.2?

Comment: а что мешает просуммировать запросом?

select sum(`ID_IL`),sum(`IL_LVL`),...,sum(`IL_COUNT`) from `table` where `id`=$N or `id`=$M";

Comment: через sum не суммирует,кстати я уже сделал спасибо knes

Comment: .

    print_r($row1); 

меняем на

    print(implode("#",$row1)); // вместо # ставим любую строку-разделитель.

Пример для строки таблицы:

    print('<tr><td>'.implode('</td><td>',$row1).'</td></tr>');

Comment: кстати я уже сделал спасибо knes//
Там есть галочка, если ответ принят.